# this facebook like button works in jsbin but not on my website?

Tags: html, facebook-like

see here in my jsbin it works fine:

http://jsbin.com/uhejis/1/edit

but i tried it on my local html page on three computers, xp, vista, and 7 and nothing
whats wrong with it??     does this code work on your local computer??

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 
"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <!-- This is all the Meta Imports and customs -->
     <head>
     <meta property="og:title" content="Albuquerque Auto Repair" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="company" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.albuquerqueautomotiveservices.com/" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/logovcm.jpg/" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Federated Automotive" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="100005049606455" />     
   </head>
            <body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
 <p>hello world</p>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/FederateAutomotive" 
data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the file to a remote or local web server (you can use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) to run a local web server) in order for the scripts to get called properly. If you open the file from your local machine, your browser will use the `file://` protocol instead of `http://` when attempting to call the scripts, and they will not be found, since your browser is looking for them on your local machine.

For clarity, here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yff6W.png) of Chrome's console when using the file protocol.